# Python: async over a list

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to write my first piece of asynchronous code. I've simplified my use-case down and have two scripts - 'main' and 's3_accessor'. The main script builds out a list of values that I then want to pass to the 'build_inventory' function.

The list has hundreds of values, so synchronous processing is slow.

---

**main.py**

```
import s3_accessor # another .py script
import asynchio

async def main():
     some_list [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
     
     for val in some_list:
          inventory_df = s3_accessor.build_inventory(val)
          s3_accessor.write_df_to_s3('some_key', inventory_df)


if __name__ == "__main__":
     loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
     loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

**s3_accessor.py**

```
async def build_inventory(val):
     ...
```

---

**Question:**

***How would I modify this code to make it such that the iteration over the list is asynchronous?***

I tried wrapping the entire for loop section in `await asyncio.wait()` but that doesn't appear to be the correct approach.

Comment: await asyncio.wait() is to avoid race condition when two processes use shared data. It is not directly related to being asynchronous or not.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to make asynchronous.  Do you want all the values in the list to happen at the same time?  Is it okay if multiple copies of `build_inventory` are running simultaneously?  Is it okay if multiple copies of `write_df_to_s3` are running simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

If, as I asked above, you're trying to handle all the values at the same time, and are okay with the calls to s3_accessor happening concurrently:

```
async def handle_one_value(val):
    inventory_df = s3_accessor.build_inventory(val)
    s3_accessor.write_df_to_s3('some_key', inventory_df)

async def main():
     some_list = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g]
     wait asyncio.gather(*(handle_one_value(val) for val in some_list))
```